# Launch Docker Container using ansible-playbook from a locally available docker image

Tags: docker, ansible

I have created a docker image with name revi-centos6. (The image has not been pushed to the docker hub)

Used the command as follows:

```
sudo docker build -t revi-centos6 .
```

The image got built successfully. Also ran `docker images` and found the newly created docker image in the list.

I have the following playbook contents (docker1.playbook):

```
# Create a a docker container on localhost (this has an ssh server in the image)
- hosts: localhost
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: start container
    docker: image=revi-centos6 hostname=test name=test detach=False state=running
```

I then ran the following command:

```
ansible-playbook --ask-sudo-pass docker1.playbook -vvvv
```

However, I got the following error:

> failed: [localhost] => {"changes": ["{\"status\":\"Pulling repository revi-centos6\"}\r\n", "{\"errorDetail\":{\"message\":\"Error: image library/revi-centos6:latest not found\"},\"error\":\"Error: image library/revi-centos6:latest not found\"}\r\n"], "failed": true, "status": ""}
>   msg: Unrecognized status from pull.

Why isn't it picking the image that was built locally and trying to look up for it from the hub? Does that mean every time I create a new docker image, I have to push it to the hub?

Note: Btw I did run `sudo docker run -t revi-centos6`, and it is able to launch the container from the locally created docker image. Problems seems to occurring only while using `ansible-playbook` command with the docker module.

Comment: You probably running the old version of module, since I don't think `running` is a valid option for current docker module

Comment: I had initially tried running it without `state=running` and I got the same error. But it was later I added that as an attempt to explicitly state it (as was found in some of the old online blogs).

Comment: So ideally, you do expect it to pick the image that is available locally right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the `docker-py` module which has had some update recently that will probe the hub for the image first. `docker-py` does not use the command-line tools, it uses its own implementation of the docker api and does things in its own way. Try running your own private registry.